# Sending a copy of email to recipient's Manager

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email, form

We have a form where users in the organization sends greetings to the random recipients. The email has to automatically copied to the recipient's Manager when they click send. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use Workflow to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

This functionality exists in 2010 workflows but not 2013 workflows. If you're working in SharePoint Designer 2013, when you create the workflow you need to select "SharePoint 2010 Workflow" as the Platform Type:

[image: Select a 2010 workflow]

Then when you're building the workflow, once the "random" user who will receive the e-mail has been selected you can run the Relational Action **Lookup Manager of User** to store that person in a workflow variable and add this variable to the e-mail's distribution:

[image]

Hope this helps!